# Lightbox Effect Not Working

Tags: gallery

I followed the steps to create a lightbox gallery. The gallery is created, but does not open with the lightbox. It just opens as a post. Does anybody know the step I've missed?

Here is the site in progress. (I also must mention that pretty much nothing in this theme I bought seems to work)

http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/absinthe/gallery/

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm relatively new to wordpress

Comment: Which tutorial you've followed? and also couple of javascript files are not being loaded correctly - see the source code

Comment: Thanks for responding. I followed the gorilla theme documentation for the dancefloor theme. What would cause the js to not load correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams like you forgot to set the Gallery Settings >  Link thumbnails to: Image File! Go to edit page/post click on edit gallery inside of your editor and at the bottom you'll find the Gallery Settings. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick, I was wondering though...can the gallery not be viewed with a lightbox effect? The lightbox works but only when you click on the select image,,you can't browse the gallery

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. If you mean that when you select Gallery Settings > Attachment Page the lightbox doesn't work. Then that is because you are telling WP to NOT use the link to the image BUT to a page. 

If you instead mean that navigating through a group of pictures doesn't work. Then that's because lightbox seams to need a rel="group_name" attribute within the <a> tag. You can use something like this $("a").attr("rel", "fancybox_group"); to add an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see that there is a 404 for a file called jquery.cycle.all.js.js and an error with mediaelement-and-player.min.js. And you're loading another copy of cycle.js, too.

Comment: I did find the 404 for jquery.cycle.all.js.js, seemed it was a typing error, The actual file did not have the double .js.js. I changed it and the error is gone. I still don't have the proper functioning of the page. The lightbox does not open, and I have an EVENTS calender that is supposed display posts that are predated. I can't seem to get the support I need from Gorilla Themes. I'm dying to get this resolved. Let the Guru's show themselves! BTW this board is awseome. I've been using the normal stackoverflow for quite sometime. Glad to find this WP site! HEELP! Thanks

Comment: You still have a JS error with mediaelement-and-player.min.js

Comment: I see the error just not 100% sure what to do about it. The media element player is working. I can't seem to understand where the error actually lies

Answer (score 0):

Just an added note- I also had this problem on my site. As it turns out, I was using the ebay affiliate program in a widget, which uses javascript. That script was interfering with the lightbox. When I removed that widget, the lightbox worked again!